# How can I travel to the north pole (Arctic areas) from Russia cheaply?

Tags: budget, russia, arctic

The best country to be able get the visa easier than the other countries to get to the north pole (Arctic area) is **Russia**. Now, how can I get there cheaply?

Comment: Define cheap please. For some people, working on an ice breaker is "cheap". For others, it's the cheapest 5-star cruiser. Or do you want to know where to get the cheapest dogsled?

Comment: Cheap means cheapest way to get there by every cheap transportation and usually not always shortest ways are cheapest too. If you check Arctic's tag you can find one question used the same term in the title but the problem was it was not about Russian part!

Comment: And even by a dogsled! I am the only cat who likes dogs! :)

Comment: Surely it is not duplicate of your question as I mentioned from Russia not Norway! And surely I am not going for a Maraton race! Right? :)

Comment: The other question has an answer on how to get there, through Moscow.

Comment: Maybe! but it doesn't mean the question is a duplicate! I didn't check all answers.

Comment: @uncovery True, but questions are duplicates if they're asking for the same thing, not if it happens that the answer is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often trips to North Pole start at Spitsbergen which is mostly Norway(one village is Russian), with one note - they are either helicopter or airplane trips and costs sthm like 15000 euro. If you would like to travel from Russia then icecutter is your choice and it is much more expensive(though longer) starting from 24000 USD and to infinity 8)). Here is link to reliable travel company [RussiaDiscovery](http://www.russiadiscovery.ru/regions/severnyy-polyus-i-russkaya-arktika/) (translate it via Google translate). Trip starts in Murmansk. Also look at tema's post about North Pole - [Tema North Pole](http://www.tema.ru/travel/90N/)(again Google translate)

Travel there is expensive. There is no commercial aviation or transport there. Just military or travel companies.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the cheapness of this but here are the options:

- [North Pole Expeditions](http://www.arcticodysseys.com/l_north_pole.html)
- [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/North_Pole)

According to [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/North_Pole) getting there would run $18-$25k.  The Arctic Expeditions doesn't provide the price but the only thing that they do state is that the Dog sled tour starts from Norway.

Comment: I want to get there from Russia not Norway!

Comment: So use the Ice Cutter. :)

Comment: I checked your first link and found something about Russian cruisers but I am sure they are dramatically expensive! Ice cutter? :)) I love it but if they let me to go with them!

Comment: @PersianCat Look at Wikitravel.  You can try seeing what you can do there.  I also found a page of a Russian expedition using Dogs and they go through Norway as well.  http://skif.onego.ru/aktivnyj-otdyh/severnyj-poljus/severnyj-poljus-ispytanie-na-sobakah-sobach-i-uprjazhki-lyzhi/

Comment: Thanks! Amazing! But for Iranian citizens Norwegians may stop me in the borders! :)(